# angularjs angular-file-upload Unknown provider: $uploadProvider error

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

This is not a duplicate of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390170/unknown-provider-uploadprovider-upload)

**I have included all the required files in view:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-file-upload-master/examples/console-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-file-upload-master/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
```

**My module and controller:**

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', ['ngGrid', 'ngDialog', 'angularFileUpload']);

controllers.controller('CustomProductsCtrl', 
 ['$scope', '$window', 'ngDialog', 'CommonService', 
   'CustomProductsServices', '$upload', 
 function ($scope, $window, ngDialog, CommonService, 
   CustomProductsServices, $upload){

});
```

But still I get this error.

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider**

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm hitting it now too

Comment: sorry dint find out @UnionP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you didn't close the `controller` declaration correctly.

Specifically, you have: `});` when you should have `}]);` instead.  Note the missing `]`.

---

In context, you should have:

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', ['ngGrid', 'ngDialog', 'angularFileUpload']);

controllers.controller('CustomProductsCtrl', 
 ['$scope', '$window', 'ngDialog', 'CommonService', 
   'CustomProductsServices', '$upload', 
 function ($scope, $window, ngDialog, CommonService, 
   CustomProductsServices, $upload){

}]);  // Note: missing ']' added in here
```

because we need to follow the form of [declaring a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).  The [controller API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) is terse, but pretty succint:

```
$controller(constructor, locals);
```

Which expanded to your case:

```
module_name.controller( 'your_Ctrl', 
    [locals, function(){ 
        } 
    ] 
);
```

I added in extra spacing to call out the missing `]` and to show how we're closing off elements within the declaration.

Answer (score 6):

Hit the same issue, turned out that the documentation to inject $upload is out of date, it should be FileUploader:

```
controllers.controller('CustomProductsCtrl',
  [..., '$upload', function (..., 'FileUploader') {
```

Spent more time than I'd like to admit figuring that out. FYI, I determined that by looking at angular-file-upload.js:

```
.factory('FileUploader', ['fileUploaderOptions', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$compile',
```

Comment: I always get $upload is an unkown provider, upon searching, I found your comment that  indicates the $upload has been renamed to FileUploader, however FileUploader.upload complains that upload is an invalid ... how can I call the upload function?

Comment: @paul-preibisch Oops, I think we're talking about two different angular-file-uploads. I believe this question was actually directed at:
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

whereas I'm using:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error can be ng-file-upload version dependent:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/45

If you try the suggestions on that page and this page and still get the error, the following worked for me:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngFileUpload'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, ... Upload) {
   ...
   file.upload = Upload.upload({...}); //Upload instead of $upload
   ...
})
```