# Angularjs-file uploading:Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider <- $upload

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to upload-file using `angularFileUpload` in php,but i will get 
this error in angular.

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider

I have tried answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800833/angularjs-angular-file-upload-unknown-provider-uploadprovider-error) question but no luck.

Here is my **app.js**

```
angular.module('app',[
'ui.router','angularFileUpload'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
        controller:'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('login',{
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
        controller:'loginCtrl'
        })
        .state('register',{
        url:'/register',
        templateUrl:'templates/register.html',
        controller:'registerCtrl'
        })
       }]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('app')
 .controller('registerCtrl',['$upload',function($scope,$http,$state,$upload){

]});
```

But still I get this error.

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider**

Comment: You have some other angular file upload. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

First why you only have $upload for the dependency injection? you should have all of your parameters.

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('registerCtrl' ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$upload', function($scope, $http, $state, $upload) {

}]);
```

You have an error at the end, first close the function, then the parenthesis and the the controller function call.

Comment: Let me try your answer